# playing video using jmf

Tags: java, swing, video, jmf

I am trying to play a video file using `JMF` but it gives me `No Media Player found exception`.

Here is my code, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

```
public class MediaPanel extends JPanel {
public MediaPanel(URL mediaURL) {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    try {
        Manager.setHint(Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true);
        Player mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer(mediaURL);
        Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
        Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

        if (video != null)

            add(video, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        if (controls != null)
            add(controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        mediaPlayer.start();
    } catch (NoPlayerException noPlayerException) {
        System.err.println("No media player found");
    } // end catch
    catch (CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException) {
        System.err.println("Could not realize media player");
    } // end catch
    catch (IOException iOException) {
        System.err.println("Error reading from the source");
    }
}
}



public class MediaTest {

public static void main(String args[]) {
    // create a file chooser
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();

    // show open file dialog
    int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) // user chose a file
    {
        URL mediaURL = null;
        Player mediaPlayer = null;

        try {
            // get the file as URL 
            mediaURL = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().toURL();
        } catch (MalformedURLException malformedURLException) {
            System.err.println("Could not create URL for the file");
        }

        if (mediaURL != null) {
            JFrame mediaTest = new JFrame("Media Tester");
            mediaTest.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

            MediaPanel mediaPanel = new MediaPanel(mediaURL);
            mediaTest.add(mediaPanel);

            mediaTest.setSize(300, 300);
            mediaTest.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
}
}
```

The exception that I am getting is `No media player found`

Comment: http://www.coderanch.com/t/537089/java/java/do-you-include-libraries-JMF

Comment: @KazekageGaara yes i do have added jmf.jar ,mediaplayer.jar..is there anything else i have to include apart from these two jars..

Comment: Did you go through that whole link? Besides, you should do `yourExceptionVariable.printStackTrace()` to get better idea of what exactly is going wrong.

Comment: i was just debugging this code and found that it is getting the videourl in mediaURL , the problem is.. it is not able to create Player

Comment: (@Echilon, please see [What to do if an edit vandalising the original post is approved?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155991/what-to-do-if-an-edit-vandalising-the-original-post-is-approved) Thanks.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What kind of video are you trying to play? JMF is a pretty old library and won't be able to play most of modern video formats, only a few old ones (i am not even sure which ones).

Actually, if I am right, to play something specific you will have to write/add your own video-encoders into JMF or at least download and use existing ones, which are usually outdated.

If you really want to have something like tunable video player that could play any modern video there are two options (in my opinion):

1. Use [vlcj](https://github.com/caprica/vlcj) library to embed [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) video player into your Java-application
2. USe JavaFX [media player](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/media/overview.htm)

I am offering only those two because I have dig through tons of libraries some time ago and there were nothing else even close to these two. Plus most of other libraries are outdated as well as JMF itself and these two are getting frequent updates and are supported with lots of users so those two are the best choice.

In case you don't mind embedding Java FX player into your application - that might be your choice.

On the other hand - vlcj is stable and easily integrated into Swing applications (its not like its hard with Java FX, but vlcj might be better for some cases).

Anyway, it is your call what to choose.

Comment: for stinky dead fish (JMF) +1

Comment: @Mikle Garin  thanks for your response , actually i am trying to use vlcj ...my main task is to capture the live video stream from an ip camera and show the video on my application ...any suggestions or simple code example using vlcj would be very helpful

Comment: @Ruby well, actually i am not that good at vlcj - just used it once in my own project some long time ago and it worked like a charm for simple video playback case (even on non-win OS). Maybe this (http://code.google.com/p/vlcj/wiki/Streaming) specific tutorial and some others on the same resource might help you start working with vlcj.