# JavaFX mediaplayer playing video in eclipse but not in runnable jar

Tags: java, swing, video, jar, javafx

I've been having this issue for some days now and cannot find the solution.
The problem is that when i run my program in eclipse my intro video shows up and plays, but when i export it in a runnable jar the video does not load, only the jframe loads.

I am using eclipse with e(fx)clipse on it.

in my main class I am just creating a Jframe and adding the MediaPanel object to the Jframe:

```
mediaPanel = new MediaPanel( "/videos/Composite2.avi" );
        frame.getContentPane().add(mediaPanel);
```

This is my MediaPanel Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.media.CannotRealizeException;
import javax.media.Manager;
import javax.media.NoPlayerException;
import javax.media.Player;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class MediaPanel extends JPanel
    {

        Player mediaPlayer;
         public MediaPanel( String mediaURL ) throws MalformedURLException
         {

            URL mediaURL1 = this.getClass().getResource(mediaURL);
            System.out.println(mediaURL1);
             setLayout( new BorderLayout() ); // use a BorderLayout

             // Use lightweight components for Swing compatibility
     Manager.setHint( Manager.LIGHTWEIGHT_RENDERER, true );

             try
             {
             // create a player to play the media specified in the URL
                  mediaPlayer = Manager.createRealizedPlayer( mediaURL1 );
                 // get the components for the video and the playback controls
                 Component video = mediaPlayer.getVisualComponent();
                 //Component controls = mediaPlayer.getControlPanelComponent();

                 if ( video != null )
                 add( video, BorderLayout.CENTER ); // add video component

                // if ( controls != null )
                 //add( controls, BorderLayout.SOUTH ); // add controls
                 mediaPlayer.start(); // start playing the media clip

             } // end try
             catch ( NoPlayerException noPlayerException )
             {
                 System.err.println( "No media player found" );
             } // end catch
             catch ( CannotRealizeException cannotRealizeException )
     {
                 System.err.println( "Could not realize media player" );
             } // end catch
             catch ( IOException iOException )
       {
             System.err.println( "Error reading from the source" );
             } // end catch
          } // end MediaPanel constructor   

         public void stop(){
             mediaPlayer.stop();
         }
    } // end class MediaPanel
```

Comment: What does 'System.out.println(mediaURL1);' show? Is it the same on Eclipse and on the jar? Did you check that the video is there?

Comment: "jar:file:/C:/Users/Sven/Desktop/Hackers%20Club/mata2.jar!/videos/Composite2.avi" this is what my console prints... also says that no media player found. And in eclipse "file:/C:/Users/Sven/workspace/HackersClub/bin/videos/Composite2.avi
" Maybe it is just a stupid mistake or i am too blind to see it for over-thinking it!

Comment: OK, now, if you open the jar with an extracter... is the folder videos in the root directory?

But if it says "no media player found"... maybe you should check the libraries inside the jar or see this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11097174/playing-video-using-jmf

Comment: The folder is there, also tried with a .flv file. Still i do not have any libraries in my project, meaning nothing but the jre8 libraries.

Comment: Solved it. I'm a moron  was trying to access the video file from the jar . That's not possible with JMF. Thank God. Thx anyway for your support

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed these libs yet.

dirac-libs-1.0.2-9.fc18.i686.rpm

libavcodec52-0.7.15-32.fc18.i686.rpm

libavformat52-0.7.15-32.fc18.i686.rpm

libavutil50-0.7.15-32.fc18.i686.rpm

libxavs1-0.1.51-2.fc18.i686.rpm

Once these were installed, javafx plays music like a charm.